# Where can I find the Drink Blood ability?

Tags: feats, pathfinder-2e, races

The [Taste Blood](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=2349) feat has a prerequisite:

> Cel Rau, Straveika, Svetocher, or another lineage from a vampire with the **Drink Blood** ability

However, when I check these lineages, there is no mention of Drink Blood.
Am I missing something, or is this an error?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## In the vampire families

Drink Blood is a creature ability that you can find on some vampire statblocks, but more generally you can find it in the 'Basic ____ Abilities' section of the main [Vampire](https://2e.aonprd.com/MonsterFamilies.aspx?ID=97) family and some of the other vampire families. *It's the vampires associated with a lineage that must have Drink Blood, not the lineage itself.*

- The [Adhyabhau](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=2342) lineage doesn't meet the prerequisite because it is associated with [Vetalaranas](https://2e.aonprd.com/MonsterFamilies.aspx?ID=311), which have Drain Thoughts instead of Drink Blood.
- The [Cel Rau](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=2343) lineage is associated with [Strigoi](https://2e.aonprd.com/MonsterFamilies.aspx?ID=314), which have Drink Essence instead of Drink Blood. However, Cel Rau meet the prerequisite anyway because they are called out directly in the Taste Blood's prerequisite. They probably received this exception because Drink Essence still involves drinking blood.
- The [Ru-Shi](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=2346) lineage doesn't meet the prerequisite because it is associated with [Jiang-Shi](https://2e.aonprd.com/MonsterFamilies.aspx?ID=286), which have Drain Qi instead of Drink Blood.
- The [Straveika](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=1337) lineage meets the prerequisite because it is associated with [Nosferatus](https://2e.aonprd.com/MonsterFamilies.aspx?ID=273), which have Drink Blood.
- The [Svetocher](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=1338) lineage meets the prerequisite because it is associated with Moroi, which are the 'generic' [Vampires](https://2e.aonprd.com/MonsterFamilies.aspx?ID=97) and therefore have Drink Blood.

As you can see, the only three lineages that meet the prerequisite of Taste Blood are already listed within the prerequisite. However, by relying on Drink Blood, Taste Blood is future proofed for the addition of new lineages and new vampire families.