# How can I use Taste Blood on level 5?

Tags: feats, pathfinder-2e, unarmed-combat

[Taste Blood](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=2349) is a 5th level ancestry feat for Dhampirs. It has [one hard prerequisite](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/206537/9552), and a soft one if you do not want to commit an evil act; **your last action must have been a fangs Strike**.

However, Dhampirs do need a feat to have a fangs Strike, very imaginatively named [Fangs](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=1336). But then you need 3 Ancestry feats to be able to get temporary hit points:

1. A lineage feat, as part of the hard prerequisite
2. The Fangs feat
3. The Taste Blood feat itself

How can I get Taste Blood before level 9?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## Ancestral Paragon

[Ancestral Paragon](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=753) is a General feat, which lets you take a 1st level Ancestry Feat.

Comment: How could I have missed it, I even have characters with this feat

Answer (score 11):

## Pick an ancestry with Fangs

Some GMs might argue that Taste Blood meant actual Dhampir fangs, but by RAW any unarmed strike qualifies that is called "fangs".

Right now the only one I can find is Nagaji.
Apart from sparing you a General feat, these have the Finesse trait, so allow Dex based builds.

Answer (score 5):

### Be a [Vampire](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=3545)

> You're a newly risen vampire. You gain the undead and vampire traits and the basic undead benefits, and your undead hunger is for the blood of the living. Your incisors elongate; you gain a fangs unarmed attack that deals 1d6 piercing damage. They're in the brawling group and have the grapple and unarmed traits.

Unironically this gives an interesting alternative to the archetype's Drain Blood action, requiring a successful bite rather than an Athletics check.

Comment: What needs an Athletics check?

Comment: @András, Drink Blood requires an Athletics check.